# What packages should I load with LuaTex?

Tags: packages, luatex, fontspec

I'd like to create my first LaTeX document to make an article for my science teacher.

I've decided to do it using LuaLaTeX, the opentype font newpx and with microtype. I'd like to use both Spanish and English.

I have preselected several libraries I think are useful and modern.

I'd like to know your opinion,
Is there any incompatibility between my packages or something unnecessary?
Do you suggest to add any other?
Would you change any option?
I'm mostly concerned about fontspec, fontenc, luainputenc y luatextra. Some posts say some are not needed anymore, some say the opposite or are too old.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[section]{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage[section]{cleveref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[xindy={language=spanish, codepage=utf8}, style=altlist]{glossaries}   
\usepackage[xindy, splitindex]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{microtype}
```

New version with your suggestions:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[section]{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage[section]{cleveref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage[xindy={language=spanish, codepage=utf8}, style=altlist]{glossaries}   
\usepackage[xindy, splitindex]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{microtype}
```

Comment: `polyglossia` loads `fontspec`. You do not need `luainputenc` -- it is made for compatibility with old documents. `luatextra` just load some other packages -- see the documentation. `Newpxtext` is not needed, since you use `fontspec`. Other packages don't seem to have anything about `luatex`, though `microtype` may have some compatibility issues.

Comment: The `mathtools` package loads the `amsmath` package automatically -- no need to load `amsmath` separately. Don't load any packages more than once (cf `biblatex`).

Comment: @Mico didn't know it. Does it apply for other languages, or English only?

Comment: Are you sure you will have a glossary and an index shipped with your article ?

Comment: @michael & Mico
but I want to use the font newpx. What should I load then?

Comment: @sztrucks Maybe just an index.

Comment: it's rather rare I think (but not necessarily wrong)  to be using newpx with luatex, why that combination? it would be more common to use newpx with pdftex or luatex with one of the TeX gyre OpenType fonts

Comment: @David.  I just want to use an opentype font similar to Palatino and fully compatible with microtype. I read it was also nice to render maths. But any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: tex gyre Pagella and its math font are perhaps a more natural match for luatex http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/pagella

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - The display-style integral symbol in the `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` math font aren't to everyone's liking. (I, for one, don't care for this symbol. I much prefer the integral symbol generated by `newpxmath`.)

Comment: @Mico yes but you don't count (nor do I:-) ... as a general rule picking out which pdflatex font and encoding packages make sense to use with luatex is a black art that you only need to learn if you need to learn it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I fully agree with you. :-) However, since the OP appears to be interested in using the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages in LuaLaTeX, he/she may well be in a "learn it if you need to learn it" situation. That's why I thought it might be useful to discuss at least a few of the pros and cons of going this route instead of (a) loading the `unicode-math` package and (b) running the instruction `setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagelle Math}`.

Comment: I've just read hundreds of posts about best practices, best fonts for maths, and best OT fonts for kerning and protrusion...  and trying to replicate in my article to avoid future problems.  But any suggestion is welcome.  What's the problem with newpx fonts?

Comment: @Mico, I don't know why I'm using \usepackage{newpxtext}  but the pdf created doesn't contain that fonts.

Comment: @skan - Which TeX distribution is installed on your computer? What happens if you open a command window and type `kpsewhich newpxtext.sty`?

Comment: I've found I also need cleveref and chngcntr.

Answer (score 4):

Some comments and suggestions:

- Load `amsmath` (or `mathtools`) *before* `fontspec` (and `unicode-math`).
- Don't load the `fontenc`, `inputenc` (or `luainputenc`) and `textcomp` packages.
- The `luatextra` package appears to have been updated last in 2010. It simply loads the following 6 packages: `fontspec`, `luatexbase`, `luacode`, `lualibs`, `metalogo`, and `fixltx2e`.

  - With a LaTeX format more recent that 2015/01/01, `fixltx2e` does nothing at all, as all of the package's various fixes have been incorporated into the LaTeX kernel code.
  - The `luatexbase` package is, these days, also loaded automatically if you run LuaLaTeX. No need to load it again.
  - In short, don't load the `luatextra` package. Load the `luacode`, `lualibs`, and/or `metalogo` packages only if you really need them.
- The `newtxtext`, `newtxmath`, `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages all interact very well with `fontspec`. If you load these packages, there's probably no need to load `unicode-math`.
- Don't load any packages more than once. (I believe this is sound advice for pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX users as well...)
- With Spanish and English, both `babel` and `polyglossia` work very well under LuaLaTeX. Just use the package whose syntax and options you find more straightforward to master.

Comment: Do you sugggest to use \usepackage{newpx} to load all newpxtext and newpxmath  or  Tex Gyre instead?
@Michael says I don't need to load fontspec if I use polyglossia.

Comment: @skan - I don't think there's a LaTeX package called `newpx`; that's why I suggested loading both `newpxtext` and `newpxmath`. (There is a much older package called `pxfonts`; its the precursor, so to say, of the `newpxtext/math` packages.) I think it's a good idea to load `fontspec` *before* loading `newpxtext` and `newpxmath`. It's up to you to decide if you want to load `fontspec` indirectly, by loading the `polyglossia` package.

Comment: If you use the geometry package you should probably load the luatex85 package using `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` BEFORE the `\documentclass` line.

Comment: @HerbSchulz why?

Comment: @skan : Sorry for taking so long to answer. Recent versions of `luatex` have changed the variable names for many pdf page properties from that used in `pdftex`, e.g., `\pdfpagewidth` became `\pagewidth`. But many packages, AFAIK including the `geometry` package, don't yet check for this change so can't set the pdf parameters in `luatex`. Similarly, if you need to use `--shell-escape` (or `write18`) you need to do a similar thing with the `shellesc` package.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I've been using --shell-escape without problems (I think) and without shellesc. When should I need it?

Comment: @skan : with luatex? What packages that require shell-escape are you using. It might be that those have been updated already.

Comment: I leave the shell-escape always there, jut in case.  What disadvantage does it have?  I use the packages aforementioned and tikz and pst-nodes.